# How to return dynamic cursor from oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 tables in which ID field is common.

I am fetching all records of first table in a cursor.
Then I want to do is that on the basis of each ID from cursor, I want to get the values from second table and then return that.

How can I do that...
Please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

homework?

this is basic SQL. generally you'd join the two tables.

```
begin
  for r_row in (select b.*
                  from tab1 a 
                       inner join tab2 b
                               on b.id = a.id)
  loop
    null; -- do whatever
  end loop;
end;
/
```

if you have an existing cursor and can't change it

eg where `your_cursor` is just returning an `ID` column.

```
begin
  open your_cursor;
  loop
    fetch your_cursor into v_id;
    exit when your_cursor%notfound;
    for r_row in (select * from tab2 b where b.id = v_id)
    loop
      null; -- do whatever here.
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

edit:
as per comments:

some sample data:

```
SQL> create table table1 (id number primary key, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 (id number, col1 varchar2(20), col2 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (1, 'test');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (2, 'foo');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into table2 values (1, 'John', 'Smith');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table2 values (1, 'Peter', 'Jones');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table2 values (1, 'Jane', 'Doe');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table2 values (2, 'Nina', 'Austin');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table2 values (2, 'Naman', 'Goyal');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

create a type to hold the return structure. note the datatypes NEED to match the datatypes of the tables `table1` and `table2` (%type won't work, so make sure they match)

```
SQL> create type my_obj as object (
  2    id number,
  3    name varchar2(20),
  4    col1 varchar2(20),
  5    col2 varchar2(20)
  6  );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> create type my_tab as table of my_obj;
  2  /

Type created.
```

now create your function (you can put this in a package if, in your real code, you have it that way).

```
SQL> create function function1
  2    return my_tab pipelined
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    for r_row in (select t1.id, t1.name, t2.col1, t2.col2
  6                    from table1 t1
  7                         inner join table2 t2
  8                                 on t1.id = t2.id)
  9    loop
 10      pipe row(my_obj(r_row.id, r_row.name, r_row.col1, r_row.col2));
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select *
  2    from table(function1);

        ID NAME                 COL1                 COL2
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 test                 John                 Smith
         1 test                 Peter                Jones
         1 test                 Jane                 Doe
         2 foo                  Nina                 Austin
         2 foo                  Naman                Goyal
```

you could pass inputs if required into that function eg `table(function1('a', 'b'));` etc..

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

The code you provided-  for r_row in (select * from tab2 b where b.id = v_id)
    loop
      null; -- do whatever here.
    end loop;

In this code I'll get values from tab2, but I want to keep these values of tab2 for few ID and return all of these values from stored procedure.  How can I do this..

Comment: @NamanGoyal how will you be using them? we can return them as an array easily enough. would that help? or do you want the output as a result set (eg do you want to do `select id from your_func()` or `return_array = your_func()` style)

Comment: Below is the code I am using-
PROCEDURE "PROCEDURE1" 
IS
id NUMBER;
name VARCHAR2 (200 Byte);
val1 VARCHAR2 (200 Byte);
val2 VARCHAR2 (200 Byte);

CURSOR cursor_ids IS
 SELECT ID, name FROM table1 

BEGIN

LOOP
 EXIT WHEN cursor_ids%NOTFOUND;
 FETCH cursor_ids INTO p_id, p_name;

 SELECT col1, col2 INTO val1, val2 
 FROM table2
END LOOP;

END "PROCEDURE1";

Suppose there are 5 records in table1.
And there are multiple entries for each id in table2.
I want to fetch latest value from table2 for each id in table1.
and then return all the data from stored procedure.

Comment: @NamanGoyal "all the data" being just the list of (col1, col2) from table2 only right or the array of (p_id, p_name, col1, col2)? and once again, do you want this as an array, or as a resultset as per my previous comment?

Comment: I want to get the data as resultset of (p_id, p_name, col1, col2)

Comment: @NamanGoyal for a result set we use a pipeline function. sample shown in the edit